How exactly do Ray resource requests compare with K8s?
I'm reading Ray's Architecture doc, and it says:

Note that because resource requests are logical, physical resource limits are not enforced by Ray. It is up to the user to specify accurate resource requirements, e.g., specifying num_cpus=n for a task with n threads. The main purposes of Ray’s resource requirements are admission control and intelligent autoscaling.

What does that mean? Are tasks guaranteed their requested resources or not?
I'm fairly comfortable talking about resource requests in K8s, so I'd like Ray's logic explained in K8s terms if possible.
Further:

Do Ray's partial CPU resources behave similarly to K8s? (a slice of CPU time)
Are partial GPU resources respected? If so, how are they implemented?
Does Ray support resource limits?

